# Understanding a Proof in Galois Theory Notes

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

My course lecture notes for Galois Theory make the following (standard) claim about the uniqueness of splitting fields for a given polynomial.

[image]

I am struggling to understand the proof the lecturer has given and think there may be a couple of errors I have identified. I'd find it very helpful if someone is able to confirm these are in fact errors, or of course to explain where my interpretation 
of the proof fails.

The given proof is:

[image]

I've underlined places where I think there is error. Firstly, the author references the field $L'$, which I think should be $M'$. Secondly, we have deduced that the extension fields $K(\alpha_1)$ and $K'(\beta_1)$ are isomorphic surely, rather than $K(\alpha_1)$ and $K(\beta_1)$. Finally, the author talks about extending the isomorphism between $L$ and $L'$, but I think he means $M$ and $M'$.

I realise these slips arise in notes, I just want to make sure my corrections are accurate before making note of them in my files.

*p.s. Unfortunately the lecturer cannot be contacted at the moment as they are away on sabbatical and have not provided an email address for students to contact him at*

Comment: You are right with your observations -  and indeed those are the kinds of slips that happen when one has to distiguish isomorphic objects or starts with a non-customary notation :)

Comment: Indeed, they seems typographics mistakes, you are right.